# Android Studio sdk directory

Tags: icons, android, android-studio, android-sdk

I installed android-studio through ./studio.sh command in terminal and manually created desktop-entry with following details in it :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.5.1
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec=bash -i "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio
Name[en_GB]=android-studio.desktop
```

Whenever I launch android-studio through icon launcher it again runs the setup wizard and ask to download sdk. I have already downloaded and configured android studio with sdk. (The location of sdk is `/root/Android/SDK` whereas the new setup wizard tries to find sdk in the `/home/user/` directory).

How do I launch the installed SDK via `.dekstop` file?

Answer (score 2):

Once you launch Android Studio, you should have a screen like this: [image]

Click on Configure and this will bring you here: [image]

Start the SDK Manager and then edit the Android SDK Location. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your sdk is in `/root/Android` instead of `/home/user/Android`.
You didn't install sdk for the account from which you are logged in, instead you installed it for root user. In this state studio will run normally if you log in as root (highly discouraged). Normally, sdk should be located in `/home/user/Android` or `/opt/Android`. Just move the sdk to the right place and everything would be alright.